# password recovery not passing req.body.email to POST

Tags: node.js, express

I'm following a tutorial on how to change your password with Nodejs

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/safe-password-resets-with-json-web-tokens/

I'm trying to pass the req.body.email to app.post, but it keeps returning undefined. req.body returns {} 
Why doesn't req.body.email have a value? This part wasn't even a Todo item from tutorial, it should just work.

I keep getting "email is missing" in console since req.body.email is undefined
Any ideas why?

```
app.get('/api/users/forgotpassword', function (req, res) {
  res.send('<form action="/api/users/passwordreset" method="POST">' +
      '<input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Enter your email address..." />' +
      '<input type="submit" value="Reset Password" />' +
  '</form>');
});


app.post('/api/users/passwordreset', function (req, res) {
  console.log("MADE IT")
  let fetchedUser;
  console.log(req.body);
  if (req.body.email !== undefined) {
      var emailAddress = req.body.email;

      // TODO: Using email, find user from your database.
      User.find({ email: emailAddress })
      .then(user => {
        fetchedUser = user;
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }

      })
```

Comment: Double-check if you have added `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` (in index.js file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `.urlencoded` body parser.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false })) // from express 4.16
```

or

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
// ...  
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```